# Error messages of nested attributes's required field are not displayed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, nested-attributes, simple-form-for

In my case, I have a client who has many tasks (which requires :detail and :completion_date fields.).
I've been building a nested model form like the following:

```
= simple_form_for @client do |f|
  = f.simple_fields_for :tasks do |task|
    = task.input :detail
    = task.input :completion_date
  = f.submit
```

When the form is submitted without either empty 'detail' or 'completion_date' field, the form is re-render but without any error messages displayed.

I've been tried to look for solutions all day. None of those mentioned about failing validation of the nested object's attributes.

Hope anybody can help!
Thanks,

Comment: have you added ```accepts_nested_attributes_for :tasks``` in your ```client``` model? for this you will need to permit the parameters as well.

Comment: Thanks @chinloong for quickly reply. Actually, I've added those already. I just haven't included in my question. Sorry about this.

Answer (score 12):

Rails does not validate associated objects  by default . You need to use the [`validates_associated` macro](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_associated).

Example:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tasks
  # Do not add this on both sides of the association
  # as it will cause infinate recursion.
  validates_associated :tasks
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
  validates_presence_of :name
end
```

---

```
@client = Client.create(tasks_attributes: [ name: "" ])
@client.errors.messages
=> {:"tasks.name"=>["can't be blank"], :tasks=>["is invalid"]}
```

The indiviaual validations errors for the associated records are not aggregated in the parent. To display the errors for the child records you need to iterate through them and call errors.full_messages.

```
@client.tasks.each do |t|
  puts t.errors.full_messages.inspect
end
```

Or when using fields for:

```
= simple_form_for @client do |f|
  = f.simple_fields_for :tasks do |task|
    - if task.object.errors.any?
       - task.object.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
         p.error 
           = message
    = task.input :detail
    = task.input :completion_date
  = f.submit
```

Comment: Thanks @max for quickly replied. Actually, my Client and Task models have been written like what you show here, but I just haven't included it in my question. Sorry about this.
Plus, I also can check the errors messages as well. My problem is that the errors messages are not displayed in the view directly on each input field (something like red border around the input box and the red error text under that).

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution to this? stuck on the same thing

Comment: The errors for the associated records are not aggregated in the parent. To display the errors for the child records you need to iterate through them and call `errors.full_messages`.